# Why Show is not restoring the form?

Tags: delphi

This is more like a theoretic question: I am curious why the `Show` method will not also restore the form (like `wsNormal`).

I know that Show does not set `WindowState`:

```
procedure TCustomForm.Show;
begin
  Visible := True;
  BringToFront;
end;
```

but why? I mean, I expect the form to actually show up on screen, when I call Show. Obviously, this will not ALWAYS happen. More exactly, it will not happen when the window is minimized.

So, what is the logic behind Show? Why they left out WindowsState?

Comment: Because `Hide` does not minimize the form, and besides if your form was maximized previously you would be miffed to have it returned to the wsNormal state after a call to `Show`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visibility and window state are simply independent properties. It is perfectly reasonably that you may wish to change one but not the other.

The design choice made by the VCL designers was to map the underlying Win32 library to the VCL in as fairly direct manner. This means that VCL designers can have flexibility to make their own choices. Were the VCL designed the way that you suggest it would make it much more difficult to change visibility without also changing window state, for example.

Comment: Agree with your explanation. But the name Show is a bit odd. The name should be 'ShowIfPossible' or 'ShowIfNowMinimized'. (just joking)

Comment: Sometimes minimized windows are visible. Try creating minimizing a form that is not your app's main form. Or the mainform when MainFormOnTaskBar is False.